# Limit of finite measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a finite measure on a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$ and let $A_{n}\in\mathcal{F}$, $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $A=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} A_n$ ($ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} A_n=\liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} A_n = \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} A_n$). I need to show that $\mu(A) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mu(A_n)$.

We know that 
$$\liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} A_n = \bigcup_{n \ge 1} \bigcap_{j \geq n} A_j,$$
and that
$$\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} A_n = \bigcap_{n \ge 1} \bigcup_{j \geq n} A_j.$$

Using a theorem, I'm able to show that 
$$\mu(A)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mu\left(\bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}A_{k}\right),$$
and that
$$\mu(A)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mu\left(\bigcap_{k=n}^{\infty}A_{k}\right).$$
Noting that
$$\mu\left(\bigcap_{k=n}^{\infty}A_{k}\right)\leq \mu(A_{n})\leq \mu\left(\bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}A_{k}\right),$$
for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, completes the proof.

Does this look right?

Comment: Looks right, but I think you can prove it more directly, without the theorem. The "standard" proof goes by showing $\mu(\lim \inf_n A_n) \leq \lim \inf_n \mu(A_n) \leq \lim \sup_n (A_n) \leq \mu(\lim \sup A_n)$.